# What are the consequences of using year of birth, rather than age, as a covariate in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, epidemiology, genetics

Would this affect the estimates of other effects in the model? Would it affect the estimated impact of age/YOB? I have a cohort but since they are all recruited at different times, I don't know which would be an appropriate endpoint to calculate age (as also many will have passed away).

I am testing multiple responses but for example, having a stroke or not. They were recruited over a period of five years and I do have access to initial dates of assessment.

Comment: Can you give some more details? What is the response? Do you know when they where recruited? ...

Comment: I am testing multiple responses but for example, having a stroke or not. They were recruited over a period of five years and I do have access to initial dates of assessment.

Comment: What is the goal of the analysis? Maybe show us both estimated models ...